# "Sorry We Can’t Complete Your Purchase at This Time" - PayPal Laravel Integration

Tags: php, laravel, paypal

I am integrating the paypal payment with a laravel api, for that I am using the [srmklive](https://github.com/srmklive/laravel-paypal) library, in sandbox mode I make the preference, and it generates a link with the value correctly, then I return that link, the frontend will run, and redirect me to the landing of success or fail, like this:

```
                $data['all purchase info'] = $purchase_variables;
                $data['return_url'] = "Success route";

                $provider = new ExpressCheckout;
                $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data);
                $response = $provider->setExpressCheckout($data, true);

                return response()->json([
                    'preference' => ($response['paypal_link'])
                ], 200);
```

And in the success route just have some mailing, and stock adjust etc...

in the sandbox it works fine, the problem is that when I go to live it generates this error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

and I don't know what it can be since I only change the mode, the username, password API and signature to the credentials live

Answer (score 1):

While it's possible that message occurs in other situations, if it occurred after your logged in or after you entered payment information, it typically indicates a normal decline.  When a customer sees this error message, they should do what the message says: return and use a different way to pay.

It is not a technical error. It is a decline. You should contact PayPal if you need more information about the decline, but typically live "test" payments to what looks like a receiver account associated with the payer (i.e. another account you own) are NOT permitted.

If you truly need to perform a live transaction for test purposes, maybe try asking a friend or acquaintance in some remote location with a PayPal account in good standing to do a $1 test.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but im trying to pay with a different account, not the same of the credentials

Comment: The same credentials would give a message about "same account as the seller".  That is not the problem here, and not relevant to my reply.  You are experiencing a standard decline message, which can occur for many reasons, including when you attempt test payments to yourself from a different account.